# Status strip progress bar

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I'm doing network scanning application. The application works fine, just I want to add `ProgressBar` which show the progress start from when user click scanning until scan completed.

```
private void scanClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (StatusLabel.Text == "Ready")
    {
        StatusLabel.Text = "Please wait while processing is done...";
    }  
    //scanning operation begins
    //label changed when scan completed
    StatusLabel.Text = "scan completed";                           
}
```

Now I have a progress bar something like this:
[image]

How to synchronize the progress bar with the scan job. Please advise.

Comment: What API you use to scan? Does that notifies you about the progress?

Comment: You could use a BackgroundWorker, for updating your progressbar.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg `BackGroundWorker` is useless if the core API you use doesn't provide progress information.

Comment: I don't see the TS talking about using an API...

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg So how'll you do scanning without using an API?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I don't have to create a networking scanning application.

Comment: +1 for recommending `BackGroundWorker`

Answer (score 1):

- If you do not know the progress in between those two comments, then you can't sync your progress bar with the scanning operation

  ```
  //scanning operation begins
  //label changed when scan completed
  ```
- One alternate is showing the progress bar moving left and right showing scanning is in progress and at the same time do not know when it will complete.
- Use a Background thread to perform the Scanning operation, perform the progress update in the main thread

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing some time consuming operation in the same thread, then update progress and call `Application.DoEvents();`.

If you are doing asynchronous operation, then update ProgressBar with `Control.Invoke` method.